# Androidx BottomNavigationView behaving strangely in different devices

Tags: android, androidx, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

1. After upgrading to

   ```
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
   ```

The Bottom Navigation View started behaving strangely on my phone. The height was set to 56dp and the icons were cropped and then when I set the height to "wrap_content" I get huge padding-bottom.

I tested it in different phones and different android versions and it behaves differently in all of them. (**Android 10.0** with height set to wrap content behaves the same as **Android 7.0** but with a smaller padding-bottom but still huge)

**'Pictures or it didn't happen':**

[image]

**Code:**

**Main.xml**

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

    android:id="@+id/main_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_bar"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_items">

</com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

**bottom_nav_bar.xml**

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorDarkBlack"/>
    <corners android:radius="1dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

**Main.java**

```
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = mMainNav.findViewById(R.id.main_nav);
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationView.getChildAt(0);
    bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++) {
        final View iconView = menuView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.icon);
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = iconView.getLayoutParams();
        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        layoutParams.height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25, displayMetrics);
        layoutParams.width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25, displayMetrics);
        iconView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
}
```

**nav_items.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/home"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_blog"
    android:icon="@drawable/glasses"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_workout"
    android:icon="@drawable/workout"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

2. What I've tried:

   - Changing back to 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' fixes the issue completely but I need the new version.
   - Changing the style to legacy `style="@style/Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView"` as stated in [documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/) does nothing.
   - Playing with padding values just increases the crop
   - Tried `<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen>` but it doesn't work also

---

I don't have a clue on what to do anymore does someone have any ideas for how can I solve this so it behaves the same in every phone?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just a guess: what if you leave out the `android:title=""` from all items? I have a feeling that in one case it actually reserves space for the empty string and in the other it's treated as having no title.

Comment: I tried removing the ```android:title=""``` and the issue remained. However, I tried to add the labels to see what the padding was. I used the tool "Show layout bounds" on my phone. What I discovered was that the extra padding is coming from the now hidden **phone navbar** as I'm using **Sticky Immersive Mode**. And it makes sense as the **Android 6.0** phone I used which presents the desired output has a physical navbar. So there must be some kind of conflict between immersive mode and the new BottomNavigationView.